# How to convert json string to object when json attributes contains space

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot

I am try to put below json string into my post request

```
{
   "Service Tracking Rule - Vesting":{
      "Service Credit Method":"Hours Counting",
      "LOA Approved - Paid Rule Required":"false",
      "LOA Approved - Unpaid Rule Required":"false",
      "LOA FMLA Rule Required":"false",
      "LOA Military Rule Required":"false",
      "Service Credit Method":"Hours Counting",
      "BIS Employment Status Rule(HC)":[
         {
            "Employment Status - Sub Status":"Leave of Absence - Approved Unpaid",
            "Hours Per Service Period":"501"
         }
      ],
      "BIS Rule Type":"Rule of Parity",
      "Computation Period":"Custom Computation Period - Vesting",
      "Custom Computation Period End Date":"1230",
      "Custom Computation Period Start Date":"0801",
      "Number of Hours":"1000",
      "key":"Service Tracking",
      "id":"6bb4e2ae-21f2-44c1-a8f7-4f9a2a9c0d65",
      "RECORD_STATUS":"COMMITTED"
   }
}
```

I want to get this json string field into one of my request POJO as below

```
public class ProcessJsonRequest {


    String serviceCreditMethod;
    String lOA_Approved_Paid_Rule_Required"
    -
    -
    -
    So on


}
```

Please guide me.

Comment: I think this is really too broad for a single question ...

Comment: Since you've annotated your question with `spring` tags, you're likely using Jackson. You want to learn how to annotate your JSON properties in your POJO, which is Jackson 101. You can start [here](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html).

Comment: Do you use annotations in your POJO?

Comment: No i did not annotate my pojo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the jackson library and annotate the **@JsonProperty** on your class fields

```
public class ProcessJsonRequest {

    @JsonProperty("Service Credit Method")
    String serviceCreditMethod;
    @JsonProperty("LOA Approved - Paid Rule Required")
    String lOA_Approved_Paid_Rule_Required"
    -
    -
    -
    So on


}
```

Comment: Yes , i am trying same.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use the dependency for jackson

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.6</version>
</dependency>
```

And map your json key with your pojo attribute.
Ex:

```
 @JsonProperty("Service Credit Method")
     private String serviceCreditMethod;
@JsonProperty("LOA Approved - Paid Rule Required")
     private String lOA_Approved_Paid_Rule_Required;
```

Other wise you have to map the json field with exact pojo attribute.